# Specifying Rails Version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I decided to upgrade to Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 4.0.0. I'm trying to set these as my default programs, by using this line:

```
rvm use 2.0.0@rails-4.0.0 --default
```

I get the error

```
Failed to load /Users/michaeldunnegan/.gemrc because it doesn't contain valid YAML hash
```

My .gemrc file is blank. I don't know what to do. I can't find any references at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

most likely it is not empty, there is a lot of `UTF-8` characters that editor will not show you, just remove the file before continuing:

```
rm -f /Users/michaeldunnegan/.gemrc
```

Comment: If I remove it, it certainly won't contain a valid YAML hash. When does rails create this file, and what, if anything, will I need to do after deleting it?

Comment: this file is not created by `rails`, it is rubygems configuration file and it does not have to exist, when it does not exist rubygems will use defaults will work just fine

Comment: Very cool, that seemed to work. Now, I'm wondering why 'rails -v' isn't giving me rails 4.0.0....

Answer (score 3):

You need to make a gemset first:

```
rvm --default use 2.0.0
rvm gemset create rails-4.0.0
rvm use 2.0.0@rails-4.0.0 --default
gem install rails
```

I think that is right.

Comment: When I run the first line, I get the error that I posted in the original post