# valid YAML hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

Every time I use a ruby involving command I get a line that goes like this:
"Failed to load /home/s/.gemrc because it doesn't contain valid YAML hash".
It doesn't cause any inconvenience, only appears after every ruby command.
Couldn't find any straightforward instructions on how to get rid of this so I thought I'd ask you

Comment: What is the contents of `/home/s/.gemrc` ? If you haven't put anything in there intentionally, you should be same to delete it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specifying Rails Version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317896/specifying-rails-version)

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
rm -f /home/s/.gemrc
```

**Edit**

It would remove your file so make sure about the file content but this will solve your problem. or you may have a backup of it and try the solution.

Comment: nooooo ! Don't "try" to delete a file, especially with the `-f` option (force). What if it contains important data?! Make sure the file is useless before deleting it (check if it is empty, eventually rename it and check if everything works fine without it, etc)